# Conventions for formatting scientific units?

Tags: formatting, best-practices, units, typography

I would appreciate some guidance on how to format units that incorporate SI, molecules, and text.

Right now I am formatting the letters in chemicals or names as 'text' and the SI units, sub/super scripts and numbers in math.

For example, I would appreciate feedback on how to format the following for publication:

- meter squared leaf area per meter squared of ground: $m^2$leaf$m^{-2}$leaf
- grams carbon: $g$C
- carbon dioxide CO$_2$

This previous question about [what package should be used to typeset units] is similar, except that I am not convinced that I need to add another package like siunitx (publishers request that I minimize use of extra packages).

Thanks!

Comment: But packages like »mhchem« and »siunitx« would make life much easier in this regard. To minimize packages means to me not to load unnecessary packages.

Comment: @Thorsten That is a good point. I guess I'll go ahead and take the plunge.

Comment: better not to anger the editor :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the SIunits package. Note that SI units are to be typeset in roman type, not italics! And please don't mix information and units. “g C”  (with a thin space) can mean only one thing, namely the product of the units gram and Coulomb. Mixing in information like C for carbon with the units is a cardinal sin. A major point of standardised units with a standardised notation is disambiguation – if you see an SI unit in a paper far from your own speciality you should still be able to understand what it means.

Please refer to the [style guides](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/rules.html) at the [NIST SI units](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/index.html) home page for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the review and for pointing out my cardinal sin. When working with information, I often find it useful to combine units and information (e.g. to keep everything straight in a calculation), but is is the proper approach when reporting a calculation to include all of the required information by using letters with subscripts rather than numbers?

Comment: I am not sure what is “proper”, but use of subscripts or explanatory text should be okay. Just so long as it cannot be confused with the units.

Comment: The NIST documents are indeed very helpful. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 3):

The siunitx package provides the `of` command that can be used in this way:

```
\si{\micro\mol\of{CO$_2$}\per\meter\squared\second\}
```

It will add the information as a subscript (or other formats specified by the `qualifier-mode`)

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
 \si{\gram\of{CO$_2$}} 
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Here are other options (from the [siunitx documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf)

[image]